# Rails 4 Pundit - policies in parent models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I'm trying to use rails 4 with pundit policies.

I have a profile model and a projects model. Projects are HABTM with profiles.

I have a project policy, that has a create? action (set to true).

In my profile show page, I want to allow users to create new projects, if they project policy create action allows it.

```
<% if policy(@project).create? %>
  <%= link_to 'CREATE A PROJECT', new_project_path, :class=>"btn btn-info"  %>
<% end %>
```

When I try this, i get a nil policy error. Is it because you can't use project actions inside profile views? If so, how do I fix it so that I can display a new project button on my profile show page?

Comment: Is `@project` defined in the controller that's rendering this page?

Comment: no it isn't ................

Comment: That means your conditional is really saying this: `<% if policy(nil).create? %>`. Which, I'd assume, is causing your nil policy error.

Comment: ah - i see. it doesnt work though if i write if policy(profile.project).create?. Any ideas for how to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ProjectPolicy.new(current_user, @project).create?` to specific `ProjectPolicy`.

However, like @miler350 said, `@project` might be `nil`. (for example: User has no project created). Make sure your `ProjectPolicy#create?` handles `nil` properly.

Comment: How do I do that? I just want to add a link to create a new project if the profile is permitted to create a new project.

Comment: maybe `<% if policy(Project).create? %>` is more appropriate in your case